# UITableView's footer is not scrolling along with the table when implemented tableView:heightForFooterInSection:

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This is how it looks when `tableView:heightForFooterInSection:` is not implemented:

[image]

Once I add this line to the code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 120
}
```

The following things happen:

1. *when I start scrolling to the bottom*

[image]

2. *when I finish scrolling to the bottom*

[image]

**Why there is a gray space fixed at the bottom of screen?** It should not be like that. What is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The footer that you set with `tableView.tableFooterView` is different from the sections footers.

Each section can have a footer whose height is specified with `tableView:heightForFooterInSection:` and the tableView itself can have a footer (below all sections). This footer is set using `tableView.tableFooterView` and you change its height simply by setting the frame of the view.

Answer (score -1):

For similar case, I used tableFooterView.

```
final class TableViewWithDynamicFooter: UITableView {
 private var isAwaitnigReloading: Bool = false
 private var lastCalculatedFooterSize: CGFloat?
 
 private func setupHeaderHeight() {
    guard let footer = self.tableFooterView else { return }
    
    let originContentHeight = self.contentSize.height - (lastCalculatedFooterSize ?? 0)
    let emptySpaceUnderContent = self.bounds.height - originContentHeight
    let minFooterHeight = footer.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize).height
    assert(minFooterHeight != 0, "Footer height constraints don't let usage of systemLayoutSizeFitting")
  
    footer.frame.size.height  = max(emptySpaceUnderContent, minFooterHeight)
    self.contentSize.height = footer.frame.origin.y + footer.frame.height
    lastCalculatedFooterSize = footer.frame.size.height
  
    isScrollEnabled = footer.frame.size.height == minFooterHeight
 }
 
 override func reloadData() {
    isAwaitnigReloading = true
    super.reloadData()
 }
 
override func layoutSubviews() {
  super.layoutSubviews()
 
 guard isAwaitnigReloading == true else { return } // allow to calculate footer size once, after reload regardless of the number of layoutSubviews calls
 setupHeaderHeight()
 isAwaitnigReloading = false
}
}
```

Demo of my implementation is here: https://github.com/ArturRuZ/TableViewWithDynamicFooter

Answer (score -2):

Just add the following code to viewDidLoad of the controller that manages the tableview:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

//...

  // Remove extra separators
  tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
}
```

Comment: No, I do not want to remove footer. I need it to be there, with variable height. Your answer will remove footer... This is not what I expect.